# Dialog Box's size is incorrect

Tags: android

I am trying to make a custom dialog box. Here is the code -

```
public static void dialogPinOptions(Context context, String pin) {

    con = context;
    dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dialog.getWindow()
            .setLayout((int) (MainActivity.width * 0.75), (int) (MainActivity.height * 0.55));

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_pin_new_user);

    dialog.show();

    /// rest of the code
}
```

I am setting the size first, and then the content to fix the size of the dialog box.

I am using the following to get the size of the screen -

```
// Getting dimensions of screen
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 11 || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 12) {

    Point size = new Point();
    try {
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        Log.i("error", "it can't work");
        }
} 
else {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;
    }
```

But I am getting incorrectly sized boxes. [Here is a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80vNt.png).

The emulator on the left has API 14, and on the right is a screenshot from my tablet with API 17.

Comment: I guess problem here `(MainActivity.width * 0.75)`

Comment: This formula has worked for me in the earlier apps I have made. But it is causing problems in this particular one.

Comment: `DisplayMetrics metrics =context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

      int  DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
     //   DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;`  then `setLayout((int) (DeviceTotalWidth * 0.75)`

Comment: Will this work for all APIs?

Comment: Test this please and give me feedback

Comment: Just checked... The problems are still there..

Comment: If you set Static Width there then ??

Comment: Yes they are static... I calculate the dimensions once in MainActivity and then use them wherever I need..